# Alphabetize results of Dir.glob

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller I have:

```
@files = Dir.glob("public/downloads/*")
```

In my view I have:

```
<% @files.each do |f| -%>
    <p><%= f.split("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/downloads/")%></p>
<% end -%>
```

How can I put the results in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be able to just:

```
@files = Dir.glob("public/downloads/*").sort
```

Comment: Thanks.  I found that when pushing an app to Heroku Dir.glob results in a differently sorted array than on my Mac at home.  thus sorting the result was essential to get my app to run.

Comment: OSX user here. This works for sorting numbered files too like "test-1.jpg", "test-2.jpg", "prod-1.jpg", "prod-2.jpg", etc.

Comment: "This works for sorting numbered files too like "test-1.jpg", "test-2.jpg", "prod-1.jpg", "prod-2.jpg", etc" as long as you don't mind `test-10.jpg` being before `test-2.jpg` (yes, I know the comment is over 10 years old by now).

Answer (score 10):

The order of the array `Dir.glob` returns depends on the operating system you use, as the [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob) states. On most computers, this is the order you'd expect, but for example on heroku the order is pretty arbitrary.

You can just sort the array by chaining `sort` to your existing method call (`Dir.glob("public/downloads/*").sort`), as the first answer suggested. However, if you use the method multiple times, it may be more convenient to create an *around alias* in order for `Dir.glob` to always return an ordered array:

```
class Dir
  class << self
    alias :original_glob :glob

    def glob(*args)
      original_glob(*args).sort
    end
  end
end
```