# Dir.glob with sort issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, filelist

As in "[Alphabetize results of Dir.glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814340/alphabetize-results-of-dir-glob?answer-4814365)", I use `sort` to get file list in alphabetical order:

```
Dir.glob("#{options[:path]}/**/*.jpg", File::FNM_CASEFOLD).sort { |file|

  dir, filename = file.match(/.+\/(.+)\/(.+)/).captures

  # ---cut---

}
```

Without the `sort` it works good, but with it fails with error:

```
$ rake slides:import -- --user foo --path /bar/baz
(in /home/user/app_folder)
"baz/ - /bar/baz/DSC_4120.JPG - saved"
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: comparison of String with 0 failed
/home/footoo/footoo/lib/tasks/slides.rake:41:in `>'
/home/footoo/footoo/lib/tasks/slides.rake:41:in `sort'
/home/footoo/footoo/lib/tasks/slides.rake:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => slides:import
```

Any idea what's wrong ?

Full code available on [Github](https://github.com/pawel7318/footoo/blob/cc4fadcb393f18a8f26d7643a637b1822eedb4b8/lib/tasks/slides.rake).

Comment: Don't say "that answer", instead use anchor text that is more descriptive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When sort is given a block it expects it to return -1,0 or 1 in order to know how to sort (a custom `<=>` function). You need to add `each` after sort to get back the default sort and the intended behavior.

```
Dir.glob("#{options[:path]}/**/*.jpg", File::FNM_CASEFOLD).sort.each{|file|
....
}
```

Read the documentation here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort

Comment: To elaborate a bit, `sort`'s block is passed a 2-element array containing two of the objects being sorted, and this array is assigned to the block variable, so here `file` equals something like `[file1,file2]`. That's why you normally see the array disambiguated into two block variables: `...sort { |file1,file2|...}`.