# Why does Dir.glob("*.txt").sort also need .each?

Tags: arrays, ruby, glob, ruby-1.9.3

`Dir.glob("*.txt")           {|f| p f}` prints filenames.

`Dir.glob("*.txt").sort      {|f| p f}` fails with an ArgumentError.

`Dir.glob("*.txt").sort.each {|f| p f}` prints filenames in alphabetical order.

Why does the second one fail?  Better yet, *why does the first one work, with or without the `.each`?*

- `Dir.glob` and `Dir.glob.sort` are both Arrays.
- `Dir.glob.methods == Dir.glob.sort.methods`.

(Inspired by [Alphabetize results of Dir.glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814340/alphabetize-results-of-dir-glob).  Not a duplicate of [Dir.glob with sort issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733611) because the "third one" already answers that one's question.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dir.glob with sort issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733611/dir-glob-with-sort-issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer is correct, but I think there is a deeper explanation. When you have a block after a method call, like `Dir.glob("*.txt") {|f| p f}`, the block is an (optional) argument to the method. In the definition of `Dir.glob`, there is a `yield` statement that runs the block.

When you chain the methods, like in `Dir.glob("*.txt").sort {|f| p f}`, the block becomes an argument to the `sort` method instead of the `glob` method. `sort` can also take a block to define a comparison, but this block doesn't make sense in that context.

Chaining `each` to get `Dir.glob("*.txt").sort.each {|f| p f}` makes the block an argument to the `each` method, which uses it like `glob` does (running the block for each argument).

Comment: So it's mere coincidence that `Dir.glob.each` and `Dir.glob` accept the same kind of block.  That's "why" `Dir.glob {}` works, with or without the `.each`.  Thanks!

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune `.each` has a return value of the object passed in so all it is doing is returning the response received from `glob`. The only time this is not true is if you use mutating methods inside `each`

Answer (score 5):

The second one fails because `sort {|f| p f}` really doesn't make sense. The block you use with `sort` is supposed to ["return -1, 0, or +1"](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) and take two arguments (the elements to be compared) but your block takes one argument and returns that argument because `p str` returns `str`.

The third one is fine because `sort`'s default comparator block is equivalent to saying:

```
sort { |a, b| a <=> b }
```

so `.sort.each` makes perfect sense.

If you use the sort of block that `sort` expects in the second example:

```
Dir.glob("*.txt").sort {|a, b| a <=> b }
```

then things will work better. Or you could just leave out the block if you want to sorting things in ascending lexical order:

```
Dir.glob('*.txt').sort
```

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Apparently [it does](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) but I'd think that's a distraction unless the OP is confusing `sort` (with a two argument block) and `sort_by` (with a one argument block).

Comment: Aha.  So sort's {} means something different than .each's {}, or .glob's {}.  Still, why the asymmetry: why doesn't .glob also need a .each?  (Is that even a meaningful question?)

Comment: Every method that takes a block has its own requirements for that block: how many arguments it gets, what it should return, ... `Dir.glob` returns an `Array`, you're probably looking at this in `irb` so you're seeing the result of `Dir.glob(...).inspect` as `inspect` is what `irb` uses to display the result of the last command.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune every method can accept a block. What it does with that block, or whether it acknowledges it at all, is determined by the method itself.